# I can't install Microsoft edge

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to install Microsoft Edge, but am getting this error:

```
sudo dpkg -i microsoft-edge-stable_97.0.1072.55-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 200165 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack microsoft-edge-stable_97.0.1072.55-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking microsoft-edge-stable (97.0.1072.55-1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive microsoft-edge-stable_97.0.1072.55-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/microsoft/msedge/locales/vi.pak' to '/opt/microsoft/msedge/locales/vi.pak.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 microsoft-edge-stable_97.0.1072.55-1_amd64.deb
```

How can I install this browser?

Comment: `compressed data is corrupt` - Check your downloaded `deb` file.

Comment: I have deb file

Comment: That `.deb` you have is either incomplete or broken. You may want to try again ...

Comment: You mean, Do I download again?

Comment: This, and check the checksum. Or simply use the repository -> https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/microsoft_edge

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Look at the end of the key error message:

```
dpkg: error processing archive microsoft-edge-stable_97.0.1072.55-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/microsoft/msedge/locales/vi.pak' to '/opt/microsoft/msedge/locales/vi.pak.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
```

There it is, in plain language: "**unexpected end of file or stream**"

Your download of the .deb package was incomplete.

Delete what you have, and download the .deb again.

Comment: Thank you so much